# C# Breaking larger method into two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I have a large method that is composed of two small methods:

```
public int LargeMethod() 
{ 
int result = 0; 
result += SmallMethodA(); 
result += SmallMethodB(); 
}
```

Both small methods block my program for atleast 2 seconds and I believe it will really be better for performance if I let the two methods run in their own threads.

Can you please suggest a programming model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 you can use tasks

```
public int LargeMethod()
{
    int result = 0;
    Task<int> t1 = new Task<int>(SmallMethodA);
    Task<int> t2 = new Task<int>(SmallMethodB);
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    result += t1.Result;
    result += t2.Result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You would only have to fork the call to A in a seperate task and just call B from the main task nd then add the result from A to it. Saves on overhead.

Comment: @gjvdkamp, Are you sure it is the right thing to do? For two tasks on dual core or better, yes, but with more tasks, not. The task scheduler works best if it has all the cores to itself, that way it can schedule your tasks to minimize context switches and/or core migration.

Comment: Minimizing the overhead is exactly what i'm trying to do by just expposing 1 task as parallel and running the other in the original thread. If you expose 2 tasks, one of them (very likely) will be done on the original thread anyway, since it's unlikely for another thread to steal it from it's queue in that short time. Might as well save the overhead of switching alltogether. Also, when you call B like this it can be inlined by the compiler. Lastly, it's just a lot less code, so less distraction from the intent of the code. (see example below). I always trim away code until it's a Haiku ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Read this **[Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)** for more information's and here you have solution:

```
Task<int>[] taskArray = new Task<int>[]
   {
       Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => SmallMethodA()),
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SmallMethodB()),           
   };

int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
{
    result += taskArray[i].Result;
}
```

Comment: Works, but breaks KISS. when the number of forks is unknown you should go with Parallel.For or Foreach.

Answer (score 1):

CLR2:

- You can define delegates for the methods, create an instance of the delegate and use the "BeginInvoke/EndInvoke" methods.
- Use the "ThreadPool" to "EnqueueWorkerItem"
- Use System.Thread to create a new Thread and start your method on it.

CLR4:

- Use the task library
- revert tot CLR2 patterns

Hope this helps,

ps; Your looking at the 'Parallel Block' pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If the operations are short, I would probably put the calls to them into anonymous methods that are executed using the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), paired with using the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class for updating the `result` variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about Tasks? Untested code below...

```
Task<int> t1 = new Task<int>(() => return SmallMethodA());
Task<int> t2 = t1.ContinueWith((t) => return t.Result + SmallMethodB());
t1.Start();
```

Of course you could just wrap up both SmallMethodA and SmallMethodB within a single task. If you're writing to the UI afterwards, be sure to use a ContinueWith task that runs on the current thread context.

Comment: This does not run them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I like Albin Sunnanbo's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303605/c-breaking-larger-method-into-two-threads/4303662#4303662)

but then with just 1 fork to make it just a bit quicker and less verbose:

```
public int LargeMethod()
{    
    var t1 = new Task<int>(SmallMethodA);
    t1.Start();
    int result = SmallMethodB();    
    result += t1.Result;    
    return result;
}
```

Edit even less like this:

```
public int LargeMethod()
    {    
        var t1 = new Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(SmallMethodA);
        return SmallMethodB() + t1.Result;
    }
```

GJ